# Building a wooden poker bag

Tags: wood

I am very knew to working with wood. What I am trying to do is a "poker suitcase". My question is how I would do the dovetailing (hope it is the right word). I have never done one so I don't know how to do so.

The Case should look like this [image]

First question: How to do such a neat dovetailing?

Question two: How is the top made? Are they just stick another wood piece on the top? Or is it nailed? How do I do that?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: The photo you attached looks like a box joint, not dovetails. You can use either one, with box joint being easier to make.

Comment: This question is a little broad. You are asking how to make a box and, how to do finger joins. These are separate topics that are broad on their own without adding more details or specifications. I suggest that you reduce this to something more specific and please include the tools you have available.

Comment: Welcome to our site! As Matt said, your question is too broad as written.  Our site works bet when questions are about a single topic (such as how to make finger joints). Therefore, it would be better to split this into two separate questions. I'm going to put this on hold; we can re-open it after you split it into separate questions.

Comment: There are [literally hundreds of resources](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+cut+a+dovetail+joint) on the internet about various methods of cutting dovetails; you should go through a few of those first. There are [probably thousands of resouces](https://www.google.com/search?q=woodworking+joints) about joining wood together; use some of your problem solving skills to find a method that works for you. You need to put a top on a box; pick a way that you like and do it. Sure, glue works. Or nails. Or screws. Or something else. Whatever, all of those things.

Comment: If you want a more complete starting guide, try ["how to build a wooden box"](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+build+a+wooden+box).

Answer (score 1):

First, in order to make this box you will need a tablesaw with a dado saw blade set. The width of each missing tooth in the box joint is important. The teeth must fit snugly in the gap of the partner piece with just enough room for glue but no visible gaps. Dado sets include shims to allow adjusting the width of a cut down to several hundredths/thousandths of an inch so you can get a great fit after several test cuts.

If you choose solid wood side panels, you may find it difficult to find wood of the desired thickness so you may need a planer to mill thicker stock to the desired profile. As an alternative, you could use plywood, but consider that the ends of the fingers may not appear as attractive as those in your image since the plywood is made of multiple layers and they may have small gaps which can show up on the ends giving a more ragged appearance. Your image also shows that the top is made of plywood which will be much easier than gluing together a top from multiple solid wood pieces, but may also have some gaps.

The next step is to make a jig so that the individual cuts for each tooth are uniformly spaced.  [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NutwD7B6tmE) by William Ng shows how to make a very simple and effective jig and how to use it effectively.  Note that the length of the teeth should be slightly longer than the depth of the gaps so that the individual teeth are just proud of the sides when glued.  Once the box sides are glued together and set up you will sand the edges flush for a smooth, flat finish.

Note that nails are not necessary for the top and bottom.  Any PVA wood glue applied along the contact surfaces should be adequate.

When you cut the side panels you will cut the width for the entire side  (do not cut the lid and bottom sides separately). The lid is cut off of the assembled box once everything, including the top and bottom are glued in place and sanded smooth.

Note that if you have a router with a flush trim bit you can trim the finger and top and bottom edges flush much easier than by had sanding them.